# "Invalid property 'xxx' of bean class" exception occurring for query string parameters

Tags: java, spring

Seeing org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException for query string parameters. 
Here are the details.
My application URL is :http://localhost:9001/xx/xx.do?param1=Hello&param2=Hai.. When I run the application, I am seeing exception for param1 and param2.
Snippet below:

```
Invalid property 'param1' of bean class [ClassName]: Bean property 'param1' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Could you please help me If somebody has seen something similar before.

Comment: could you please paste some code here?

Comment: Thank you.
As part of my JSP, I have not defined any param1 or param2. I am just passing some static parameters from each JSP.
Jsp: <form:form modelAttribute="BeanName" action="/xx/xx.do?param1=Hello&param2=Hai." >
And, neither my bean has any information about these two parameters.
My logic is, Read the query parameter from the request object and execute required logic.
Controller:
    @RequestMapping(value = "/xx.do")
    public ModelAndView handle(HSR req,HSRes res,@ModelAttribute("BeanName") BeanNameClass BeanName,BindingResult result) {
String pa1= req.getParameter("param1");